# having ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error on my maxcdn bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, cdn, connection-timeout

I'm getting the error of `GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in my console. I have place the correct URL but it does not load. May i know how can i solve this issue?

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/img/logo.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/img/logo.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    MyWebSite
  </title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./assets/css/paper-dashboard.css?v=2.0.1" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="./assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .card-title {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

It cause my icons in my website were unable to show
[Which is shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcVbh.png)

```html
<div class="text-center">
                <a href="sales-analysis.php" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="nc-icon nc-paper"></i> &emsp; View Sales Analysis</a>
                <a href="top-categories.php" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="nc-icon nc-bullet-list-67"></i> &emsp;  View Top Categories </a>
                <a href="top-customer.php" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &emsp; View Top Customers </a>
                <a href="top-stock.php" class="btn btn-info" > <i class="nc-icon nc-app"></i> &emsp;  View Top Stock </a>
                <a href="top-sales.php" class="btn btn-info" > <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> &emsp;  View Top Sales </a>
                <a href="top-area.php" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> &emsp; View Top Area</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? are using any vpn?